# R program: i am not able to print "NA" if the values are not found/matching

Tags: r, na

I am new to this "R", I  have written a program in R which pulls the data from one flat file and matches the probe IDS (its microarray data) with another file which contains gene annotations(name, Symbol, synonyms, ect). I can pull out the those ids which matches with genes , but i am not able to figure out the one which are not matching. I wanted to Print "NA" to a particular ID which doesn't have any match for GENE name/synonyms. The code is as follows.

```
## Getting the probe.ids with gene names
probe <- read.delim("super.txt",stringsAsFactors=F, header = T, sep="\t")
probe$probeid<-tolower(probe$probeid)
## Matching with probe ids which dosnt have any annotation
names<-read.delim("GSE42568_probeid.txt", as.is=T, stringsAsFactors=F, header=T)

names<-names$probeid
vec<- NULL

system.time({
#lenght of genenames, i:e total gene names in the file
 for(i in 1:11390){
cat("Index of required name is ",grep(names[i],probe$probeid,fixed=T), "\n")
index<-grep(names[i],probe$probeid,fixed=T)
 vec<-c(vec,index)
 }
})
vec_1 <- data.frame(probe[vec,]) 

write.table(vec_1, file = "probeids_matched.txt", row.names = FALSE, append = FALSE,   col.names = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

I am relly sorry for posting such silly questions, but i tried all sort of things, it dint worked for me... :( 
thanks a lot.

```
structure(c("function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, ", 
"    verbose = getOption(\"verbose\"), envir = .GlobalEnv) ", 
"{", "    fileExt <- function(x) {", "        db <- grepl(\"\\\\.[^.]+\\\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$\", x)", 
"        ans <- sub(\".*\\\\.\", \"\", x)", "        ans[db] <- sub(\".*\\\\.([^.]+\\\\.)(gz|bz2|xz)$\", \"\\\\1\\\\2\", ", 
"            x[db])", "        ans", "    }", "    names <- c(as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1L]), list)", 
"    if (!is.null(package)) {", "        if (!is.character(package)) ", 
"            stop(\"'package' must be a character string or NULL\")", 
"        if (any(package %in% \"base\")) ", "            warning(\"datasets have been moved from package 'base' to package 'datasets'\")", 
"        if (any(package %in% \"stats\")) ", "            warning(\"datasets have been moved from package 'stats' to package 'datasets'\")", 
"        package[package %in% c(\"base\", \"stats\")] <- \"datasets\"", 
"    }"), .Dim = c(20L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), ""), class = "noquote")
```

Current Output is :

-Index of required name is  2164 2165 
 -Index of required name is  2182 
 -Index of required name is
 -Index of required name is
 -Index of required name is
 -Index of required name is  2751

Output Required  :

- Index of required name is  2164 2165
- Index of required name is  2182
- Index of required name is   **NA**
- Index of required name is   **NA**
- Index of required name is   **NA**
- Index of required name is  2751

Comment: It would be  helpful for others to check the code if you provided a reproducible example, preferably using `dput`. ie. `dput(head(data, 20)` and paste the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thik this is what you are looking for:

```
vec_NA <- data.frame(probe[-vec,])
```

EDITED: To produce the message you want correct your code as follows

```
NoMatchID = NULL
for (i in 1:11390){
  index<-grep(names[i],probe$probeid,fixed=T)
  if (length(index)!=0) {
    cat("Index of", names[i],"is", index, "\n")
  } else {
    cat("Index of", names[i], "is NA \n")
    NoMatchID = c(NoMatchID,i)
  }
}
```

Note that NoMatchID are IDs from your vector of names. If you want IDs from your dataframe probe do

```
NoMatchID_probe = setdiff(1:nrow(probe), unique(vec))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! but still i am not able to get NA against those indexes which doesn't match.Please have a look onto the edited question.